# Can I print the content of the rax register with leading zeros?

Tags: gdb, hex, x86-64

When I print the content of the `eax` register in a gdb session in hexadecimal format, it does not print leading zeros:

```
(gdb) p/x $rax
$6 = 0x3
```

I am looking for a possibility to extend the output to print all 16 hexadecimal digits so that the output becomes

```
$6 = 0x0000000000000003
```

Is there such a feature?

Comment: `printf "%016lx", $rax`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: this worsk perfectly. If you turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `printf` command to use *C* [`printf` like format strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to format the output.

You can print `long` values with `%lx`. Prepend `lx` with a size like 16 will format a number right justified in the field of the specified size. If you prepend a `0` to the size it will zero fill for you. This should work:

```
printf "%016lx", $rax
```

If you want `0x` to appear you can add it yourself with:

```
printf "0x%016lx", $rax
```